# Opening a sparsebundle file without TM

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, time-capsule, sparsebundle

A few months ago I had to make a backup on my Time Capsule (from 2008 lol) before resetting my MacBook Air (battery change and all). But since I got it back, I had no way to open/access my save. I can click on the `sparsebundle` file but it doesn't show up in the program Time Machine; nothing does actually. It's 107GB and clicking on it manually does nothing. I have tried mounting it with disk utility, it's not damaged, but I can't seem to restore it or don't know how to.

I don't need to restore the whole thing, only to access some files to get schoolwork.

If anyone has any ideas or ways to get it back, please do share.
Also if I haven't given enough information on the computer or something, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Where did you backup to?

Comment: A .sparsebundle *should* just open and mount on the desktop. If it does not it may be damaged somehow. You can also select a TM backup by holding OPTION while selecting the TimeMachine menu and then point it at the .sparsebundle. Have you tried that?

Comment: @nohillside I made the backup on my mac and it saved on time capsule before it went to reparation and got reseted. I could see the file in time machine back then. Now it appears on time capsule still, but i can't do anything with it

Comment: @SteveChambers Do you know how i could know if the backup is damaged? I just tried doing what you said but it didn't appear on the list of saved disks from the menu. I tried dragging the sparsebundle file into it and it didn't work either.

Comment: A sparsebundle on a remote drive (NAS or Time Capsule) can take _very long_ to open with no obvious indication of progress, so one can easily think it doesn't do anything at all (had that happen to myself, too). How long did you wait?

Comment: @not2savvy The first few times i tried to open it it did take long, maybe about 30 minutes before the TM file appeared on the left bar of the finder. But now it "load" way quicker (only takes about 5 minutes), but it is still the same result. I can post pictures if needed

Comment: Sorry, then I don't understand what exactly your question is. I suggest that to edit your question to make clearer what you tried, what the result was, and what you are asking for.

Comment: @not2savvy I see how it can be confusing now reading it again. When i say it opens it's as in i do have a box saying it's checking the volumes and all of the save before opening it. But when i go to see what's supposed to be inside, nothing appears on TM as a backup from 18/07 (when i made the save). I want to be able to access what's inside it, even if it's by finder only.

Comment: Post some screenshots of the bundle mounted in Finder, please. Just add them to your question. This will give people a better understanding what it looks like for you.